# Не корректно отображается Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, iframe

У меня есть верстка страницы, когда я ее запускаю в браузере она отображается корректно, но когда я ее запускаю в Iframe содержимое уменьшается, уменьшается не сам Ифрейм, его я уже растянул на всю ширину и высоту, а уменьшатся как ZOOM.
То есть у меня есть контейнер внутри документа который я поключаю в этом Iframe, когда я открываю его в браузере у него есть свойства:

```
@media (min-width: 1920px)
.container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    max-width: 1478px;
}
```

Когда я открываю его через Iframe то стили меняются:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
    max-width: 1220px;
```

Хотя ифрейм полноекранный, как пофиксить это?
}

Comment: можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: Сайт на локальном хосте